# ES256 algorithm credentials - how to use them

Tags: python, api, token

I have a set of credentials that should be used to retrieve data from an API.
The file I currently have decrypted is a dictionary with "id", "secret", "public_key", "algorithm", "private_key", "key_id".
I am currently using python and I need to get data from a web API using a bearer Authorization (I also have the url).

My question is: looking at the information I have right now, what can I use as a token? How does it look like?
I tried using the file all together, the public_key, private_key, etc... but nothing works. Do I still need to decode anything before starting making calls to the API?

Thanks!

Comment: Without reading the documentation of the API you're trying to connect I'd say this is a JWT token, so try using PyJWT to generate the authorization